# Proving that the center of an abstract Lie Algebra is non-trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $\varphi:L\to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ a representation of $L$ s.t for every $x\in L$, $\varphi(x)\in\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is nilpotent. Prove that there exists some $0\neq v\in V$ s.t $\varphi(x)v=0$ for every $x\in L$ and deduce that $Z(L)\neq \{0\}$.

I was able to prove the first part (the existence of the vector $v$). I am however stuck on the second half of the problem. I was able to deduce that $Z(\varphi(L))\neq\{0\}$, but not that $Z(L)\neq\{0\}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can deduce that $\phi(L)$ is a nilpotent Lie subalgebra (either by applying Engel's theorem or by finding a complete flag preserved by the algebra, i.e after finding $v$, considering the quotient representation and inducting on the dimension). So it has a non trivial center, but an arbitrary representation cannot tell anything about the algebra $L$, for example, the trivial representation of any algebra consists of nilpotent maps. Moreover, one can deduce that $L/Ker(\phi)$ is nilpotent, but we don't know anything about $Ker(\phi)$, even if it is a nilpotent ideal, because there are non nilpotent Lie algebras with a nilpotent ideal and a nilpotent quotient. I think there are some missing pieces in this exercise, either the representation $\phi$ is the adjoint representation, or $Ker(\phi) \subset Z(L)$ (a central extension of a nilpotent Lie algebra is nilpotent) or something else.